# How do abstentions affect Majority Judgment voting?

Tags: voting-systems, range-voting, strategic-voting

In the examples of [Majority Judgment on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_judgment) et al, every voter submits a rating of every candidate, conveniently making the vote bars equal width. What happens when that doesn't happen?

In ordinal systems (Plurality, Ranked, Borda, etc), abstentions are mathematically equivalent to "nay" votes. That's not the case in MJ, so I'm wondering if abstentions can be used in strategic voting, or lead to paradoxical outcomes.

Comment: In the first illustration in your wiki link, an example of a ballot for Majority Judgment, there is a mention "leaving a candidate blank gives them an F." This looks like a way of handling partial abstention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most systems of Majority Judgement an abstention is treated as giving the lowest possible judgement of a candidate. Note for example in the link you give "Leaving a candidate blank gives them an F".

Since an abstention is treated as a particular type of vote, it can't be used tactically. In effect, you can't abstain on any of the candidates.

Comment: Perhaps you could outline a tactical abstention.